# ANSI C - Two-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, ansi-c

I'm trying to asign float values into a two dimensional array using a `for` loop. That has been declared as `float num[4][7];`

This is my code so far:

```
float num[4][7];
int x;
for(x=0;x<=3;x++) {
    printf("Enter number: %d",x);
    scanf("%f",cad[x][x]);
}
return 0;
```

But seems like it's not working properly, it's not doing what I explained before..

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Compile your code with `-Wall` (show all warnings); the compiler will generally catch mistakes like this.

Comment: What's `cad`? Why are you reading into `cad`, when you wanted to read into `num`?

Comment: Still in doubt why `[x][x]` is used?

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf("%f",cad[x][x]);
```

use instead:

```
scanf("%f", &cad[x][x]);
```

The argument for `%f` conversion specification in `scanf` has to be a pointer to `float`. You were using an argument of type `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Three issues, first, as has been mentioned, when using [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) you need to give it a pointer to what it's going to update:

```
         //    v-----added that
    scanf("%f",&cad[x][x]);
```

Second you initialize an array called "num", but you populate an array called "cad". So change one of those, the names have to match.

Finally, your loop will only populate 4 of the total 28 elements:

```
//This
float num[4][7];
for(x=0;x<=3;x++) {
  scanf("%f",&num[x][x]);

//Will give you:
[%f][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][%f][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][%f][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][%f]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ]
```

Obviously in that example the `%f`'s are replaced by whatever you typed in. To populate the whole array you need to have two for loops, `x<=3` (for the columns) and `y<=6` (for the rows)

```
float num[4][7];
int x;
int y;
for(x=0;x<=3;x++) {
    for(y=0; y<=6; y++) {
        printf("Enter number: [%d][%d]",x,y);
        scanf("%f",num[x][y]);
    }
}
```